# how can I redirect 404 error page to homepage in blogger

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-404, blogger, blogspot

I have deleted many posts from my site and I want to redirect my broken 404 error pages to homepage automatically so anyone can tell me how to redirect 404 error pages to homepage in **blogger blogspot** with easy steps.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add 404 redirect template .

```
BSPNF_redirect = setTimeout( function() {

location.pathname= "/"

}, 5000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it by the following way.

```html
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;error_page&quot;'>
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=yourhomepageurl' />
</b:if>
```

Just paste above code to below the below code inside your Blogger dashboard.

```html
<b:include data="blog" name="all-head-content"/>
```